# Can't deploy custom content type

Tags: content-type, error, feature-activation

I have an content type in my feature, and sudenly when I tried to debug my feature, i got the following error:

```
Error occurred in deployment step 'Activate Features': 
The content type with Id 0x01005B614C2D37A841DE8D1739C2A6ECDF82 defined in feature {bla bla} was found in the current site collection or in a subsite.
```

The thing is that even if I manually retract and delete solution and try to redeploy, error is still present. I can't find my content type in gallery, nor activate feature containing it by hand from feature gallery. I found it in content database by hand (through SQL Server Studio), but I'm far from deleting it by hand from database because I don't want to mess up whole site collection and web application. What can be the cause and how do I eventually can get rid of that error?

I found one post on MSDN which suggested site collection deletion, but I'd like to avoid that.

Comment: Running 'iisreset' before feature activation also works. Not very efficient maybe, but for development it works ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug that comes up every now and then.  Sometimes it will clean itself up when you redeploy.  Try that before deleting the site collection.

Comment: Today everything works fine...

Comment: Anita's answer was most correct.  It is the restarting of VS that clears things out.

Answer (score 3):

Try restarting Visual Studio. Sometimes it locks some stuff, I've seen it before.

Answer (score 1):

I faced this issue before but did you to iterate through the Site Collection/Webs via PowerShell to see if something is missing?

Also, check the ULS log to find more specific information. Did you try setting the **OVERWRITE attribute to TRUE** because it overwrites the existing Content Type if any. If you don't find anything, (as Mike suggested) you may have to delete the Site Collection and recreate it.

Comment: yes, I did iterate through site content types with powershell script, and I couldn't find my content type. I think I tried also OVERWRITE=True, but it didn't work. Will try it again thou.

Answer (score 1):

The issue comes every now and then.. in the case try to retract the code with visual studio. rebuild it and again deploy. Or may be you can put activation status to "No Activation" and then deploy your solution.

Hope it works...

--
regards,

Deepak

Answer (score 0):

I deployed a bunch of columns and deployed them using a feature. Afterwards I retracted that feature and created a new feature to deploy them with same ID (GUID) but different internal names. That caused me this error.

I had to change all my IDs to fix this issue.